# Zotero does not find pdftext and pdfinfo

Tags: 12.04, pdf, official-repositories, zotero

I am using the Firefox extension Zotero on 12.04. Zotero complains about missing PDF tools, though:

```
To use this feature, you must first install 
the PDF tools in the Search pane of the Zotero preferences.
```

and

```
Available downloads for Linux x86_64 from zotero.org:
- pdftotext version 3.02
- pdfinfo version 3.02
Zotero can automatically install these applications into the Zotero data directory.
```

So the missing PDF tools appear to be pdftotext & pdfinfo. However, they should already be available (in older versions) via the installed Ubuntu package `poppler-utils`.

Why doesn't Zotero find these programs? Of course, I could just reinstall them in the suggested way but generally I prefer to install software only from the Ubuntu repository.

Comment: Please open a shell and type `which pdftotext` --- if it gives a result, either a) Zotero extension is buggy or b) it needs a different version. (Strange --- in 14.04 my `pdftotext` says it's on version 0.24.5 --- could they really be different tools with the same name?)

Comment: `which pdftotext` gives `/usr/bin/pdftotext`; version is 0.18.4

Comment: In case you're courious about the different version numbers: Zotero uses pdftotext straight from Xpdf (the most recent versino there is 3.0.4). In Ubuntu (as in most distros) it's packed with poppler, which uses a different versioning system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Zotero [documentation](https://www.zotero.org/support/pdf_fulltext_indexing)

> Zotero uses customized, platform-specific versions of the pdfinfo and
>   pdftotext utilities from the open-source Xpdf project for PDF
>   indexing. Specifically, Zotero uses modified binaries of pdfinfo and
>   pdftotext on Windows to prevent the command-prompt window from
>   appearing at indexing time, and a custom build of pdfinfo on all
>   platforms that support writing to a text file (see source code).

So this is expected behavior on the part of both Zotero and Ubuntu. (FWIW, though "install software" is a rather strong word here: it just downloads two files and places them in the Zotero data folder)